# Reading Cyrillic text from CSV / JSON with d3

Tags: javascript, json, csv, d3.js, cyrillic

I would like to import Cyrillic text from CSV or JSON using d3 (for the purpose of a [bubble chart visualisation](http://vallandingham.me/bubble_charts_with_d3v4.html))

Once loaded with either of the functions:

```
d3.csv('spendings.csv', function(data) {
  console.log(data[0]);
});
```

or

```
d3.json('spendings.json', function(data) {
  console.log(data[0]);
});
```

the text

> Многопрофилна болница за активно лечение /МБАЛ/ "Света Анна" АД - София

looks something like this in the DOM console:

> M������������ ������� �� ������� ������� /����/ "����� ����" �� - �����

This tells me that the problem is not with the HTML encoding, but rather with the way Cyrillic text is read by d3.js

Comment: Use Windows-1251 charset encoding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Cyrillic in D3.

1.HTML:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```

2. use utf-8 in editor .html .csv .json files

Comment: Saving the csv / json files with utf-8 encoding solves the issue. Thanks.